# Python - re.search - re.compile

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-parsing

I'm new at this and still trying to get the parsing to work right. Any suggestions.

```
import urllib2
import re

## Open Connection ##
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
oururl = opener.open('http://www.ip-lookup.net')

## IP Addresss finder ##
theIP = re.compile(r"d{1,3}.d{1,3}.d{1,3}.d{1,3}")
ip = re.search(theIP, str(oururl))

## Country finder ##
roughCountry = re.compile('([A-Z]\w+)( [A-Z]\w+){0,2}(?=\<\/a\>\s\s)')
Country = re.search(roughCountry, str(oururl))

## Print out ##
print "Your IP is:", ip
print "Your Country is:", Country
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you looking for modules to scrape the page? Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: At this point the "oururl" does get the website. I'm trying to use IP Address Finder to get the ip address listed on the website and Country Finder to find the country listed on the website. At this point it returns "None" which I know is not true since I see what I'm looking for in "oururl". My questions is why is the return None and not the values I'm trying to get?

Comment: It's possible that the content is dynamically generated and your `oururl` is actually not what you think it is.  You might see the content on your browser but your program could be receiving something entirely different.  One easy way to verify is saving the page received from `oururl` as test.html or something and open it on your browser, see if you can still find the elements you expect to find.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the escaping backslash in front of your digits in `theIP` and the dot. `d{1,3}.d{1,3}.d{1,3}.d{1,3}` matches things like `dd.dddxdd(ddd`. The regex you tried to implement I guess is `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}`

But be careful, this will also match ips like 923.234.512.235 which obviously allows numbers greater than 255. For a regex that restricts to nubers from 0-255 just give google a try. There are a million examples on an ip regex. E.g. have a look [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) or [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html).